# Link stretches across whole page (using image as link)

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, center

I'm trying to assign different images as links but the hyperlink seems to extend to the rest of the page (horizontally).

This is what the images look like as links, however (as mentioned above) they extend to both sides but are fine on top and on the bottom. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP6Pu.jpg

How would I prevent this from happening?

HTML:

```
<body>

    <ul id="navbar">

        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="anime.html">Anime</a></li>
        <li><a href="form.html">Whats your opinion?</a></li>

    </ul>

    <div class="animemid">

    <!-- Black Clover -->

        <div class="bc">
            <a class="link" href="blackclover.html">
                    <img style="vertical-align:middle" id="bcImg" src="assets/blackclover.jpg" width="400" height="225">
                    <h2 id="bcTag">Black Clover</h2>
            </a>
        </div>

    <!-- My Hero Academia -->

        <div class="mha">
            <a class="link" href="myheroacademia.html">
                    <img style="vertical-align:middle" id="mhaImg" src="assets/deku.png" width="400" height="225">
                    <h2 id="mhaTag">My Hero Academia</h2>
            </a>
        </div>

    <!-- Haikyuu!! -->

        <div class="hky">
            <a class="link" href="haikyuu.html">
                    <img style="vertical-align:middle" id="hkyImg" src="assets/haikyuuPage.jpg" width="400" height="225">
                    <h2 id="hkyTag">Haikyuu!!</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.animemid {
    margin-top: 69.5px;
}

.animemid h2 {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.animemid img {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    opacity: 0.75;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.animemid div {
    position: relative;
}
```

Thanks in advance,
e

Answer (score 0):

H2 is a block element.

Change it to inline (or inline-block):

```
.animemid h2 {
   display:inline;
```

Comment: I tried this but it changes nothing, adding either 'inline' or 'inline-block'.